# getJson and push into array

Tags: jquery

I'm hoping someone can help me get the following `getJson` call going. I want to retrieve all the names which are buried in under `features.attributes.NAME`. See the sample json

```
  {
    "objectIdFieldName": "FID",   
    "globalIdFieldName": "",
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
    "spatialReference": {},
    "fields": [],
    "features": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "NAME": "ST. JOHNS"
            }
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "NAME": "HAYDEN ISLAND"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Using jquery I'm currently trying something like this to create a blank array and push the names into it.

```
$.getJSON("url/myjson", function(data) {
    items = [];
    $.each( data, function(i) {
        items.push(data.features.attributes.NAME);
    });
});
```

The error I'm getting at the moment says `Cannot read property 'NAME' of undefined.`

Comment: I was having issues like this, and what I was missing was actually parsing in the JSON received into an object.  Until you do that, you cannot actually reference into the JSON with data.features (or whatever properties you have in the JSON).
Here:
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
Now you can do what you need to do with:
items.push(obj.features.attributes.NAME);

Answer (score 5):

You need to use something like this:

```
var items = []; // empty array
$.each( data.features, function(index, value) {
  items.push(value.attributes.NAME);
});
```

The first parameter of the each function needs to be an array. You passed the whole object to it, containing the fields objectIdFieldName and so on.. I've changed that to pass only the features-array.

The next issue was with the callback you provided. It has two parameters: index and value. Index is the number of the current loop round. In value are the data you wanted to access.

Then I also changed the items.push-call appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$.each` will tread the first argument as an array-like object. `data` returned from `getJSON` is your object, not an array.

Doing the following

```
var items = $.map(data.features, function (i) {
    return i.attributes.NAME;
});
console.log(items);
```

produces `[ "ST. JOHNS", "HAYDEN ISLAND" ]`.

This has the added benefit of not relying on side-effects in the callback for `each`, by using `map`. This means you don't need to push elements into the array, as they are constructed *from* the data.